# Import data in Excel from SQL

Tags: sql, excel

How to import data into Excel from SQL table (Compiled Data) containing "935269" rows. I am unable to copy paste in Excel. Kindly let me know if I can import the data in Excel with the query or any other method.

Comment: you use export data csv for ms excel in option

Comment: Output your query results to a text file and open that file with excel.

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio: right click on Database -> Tasks -> Export Data

Comment: by the way: don't be afraid of using search engines. they might help you

Comment: the search engine is also telling me the steps you have mentioned but I want to know the query of one liner if exist as mentioned in the question. For every database and every table of each DB doing the steps, again and again, might not be helpful.

Comment: Your most recent comment makes it very unclear what you are attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Data tab, select New Query and then select From database. Select the database engine you need. Then in a Wizard select your table.

[image]

Comment: let me try hoping this wizard will capture my "935269" rows from SQL DB.

Comment: I tried it for about one million rows and it worked (on SQL Server).